# I cannot find the local codePool in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, codepools

I am using magento 1.9 in ubuntu and the code folder does not consist of local .

The **Mage.php** consist of
Mage.php -

```
/**
 * Set include path
 */
$paths = array();
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'local';
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'community';
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'core';
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'lib';
```

but after the command : cd /var/www/html/magento/app/code/
                      : ls
it only shows -->     : community   core

I am stuck in step one http://www.codexpedia.com/magento/create-read-update-and-delete-with-magento-database/
Please Help

Comment: magento does not provide it by default. you need to create it if you need it

Comment: can u help me with it ??

Comment: How to create local in ubuntu??

Comment: create folder "local" under `app/ code` :)

Comment: But how to enable it for operation ??                                                                               because i tried to save and i got this message : Operation not permitted

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. Please do not ask the same question twice. If you want to add more information to your question, you can edit the original one.

Comment: @Anuja might be file permission issue.

Answer (score 1):

**By default magento doesn't have local codepool**. This need to be created if we are doing some project level customization by using custom module.

For extensions also its not recommended to use local codepool instead extension developer should use community codepool only

Some more important information:

```
$paths = array();
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'local';
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'community';
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'core';
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'lib';
```

Above code says to Magento:

> "Look for any specific file in `local` first, then look inside
>   `community` then look inside `core` then last look inside `lib`"

Because of this only we can override core files just by putting in local code pool using the same path.